# club / closure points

Tags: set-theory

I have a question concerning set theory and I would really appreciate anyone's help.

Namely, I am supposed to show that if $C$ is club in $κ$, then there is a function 
$f : κ → κ$ with $C_f ⊆ C$.

Here $C_f$ stands for the set of closure points of $f$, i.e. 
$$C_f = \{α < κ | f[α] ⊆ α, α > 0\}.$$
And of course, for $κ$ I suppose that it is regular, uncountable cardinal.
Thanks in advance for all the possible hints.

Comment: $C_f \subset C$ because $C$ is closed. Are you asking for an order-isomorphic $f:k\to C_f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Use the natural enumeration surjection $f:\kappa\to C$, so that $f(\alpha)<f(\beta)$ whenever $\alpha<\beta<\kappa$. You may find it helpful to show that $\alpha\le f(\alpha)$ for each $\alpha<\kappa$.